# #1045 - Unknown error 1045 in mysql login

Tags: phpmyadmin

In terminal I executed the following:

```
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

And got the result:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Unknown error 1045
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the password is right? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_access_denied_error indicates that 1045 means you access have been denied. You could reset the password like described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt yes my password is ok,  you give a link that is after login in mysql, but i cant login when i enter my password i got this error, same error i got in browser in login page when i give username/password.

Answer (score 1):

Am using Ubuntu-16.04 with installed mysql - 5.7. I Had the same issue.

I tried the below steps:

1. `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql` (to get the version of mysql).
2. `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`
3. `mysql -u root -p`

Without `-p` that doesn't prompt you to ask password. Once you are in, you can create a user with a password by following steps :

```
CREATE USER '-your_name-'@'your-hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . to '-your_name-'@'your-hostname' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Exit from the root and login from the you gave above.

```
mysql -u -p
```

For some reason still just typing mysql does not work. AT ALL. Please let me know if this works, else I have other steps.

Answer (score 0):

I share here my experience, hoping it might be useful.

I solved the problem on my environement (Ubuntu 18.04.3, mysql 14.14, Distribution 5.7.27 ) as such:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

Then I created a user as suggested by @Nikhil Rushmith:

```
CREATE USER 'new_username'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . to 'new_username'@'hostname' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Finally I created a database `mydb` and granted all rights to it to the new user `new_username`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'new_username'@'hostname';
```

After that, I quit mysql and connected with the new user, and could acess to the new database.